# horizontal nav bar / unordered list

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a simple nav bar with a `<ul>` and am trying to make the `<li>` items stack horizontal instead of vertical. I placed the `display:inline` code in my css, but the list items still remain vertical. Any help would be appreciated!

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li> Home </li>
        <li> Farm Park </li>
        <li> Cafe </li>
        <li> Goods </li>
        <li> Gallery </li>
        <li> Contact </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and my CSS is just

```
#li {
    display: inline;
 }
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors

Comment: remove the '#' from the selector, you created a selector for `id="li"` ...

Answer (score 6):

the selector is `li`, not `#li`. the `#li` selector applies for the element with `id ="li"`. the `li` selector applies to the `<li>` elements

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li> Home </li>
    <li> Farm Park </li>
    <li> Cafe </li>
    <li> Goods </li>
    <li> Gallery </li>
    <li> Contact </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
#li {
     display: inline;
 }
```

to

```
#nav li {
     display: inline;
 }
```

or

```
li {
     display: inline;
 }
```